# Could not find com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.2.2

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, sdk, crashlytics

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.2.2.
> Required by:
> project :app

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, this is super annoying, and has to do with their migration. You wanna visit [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) documentation page to get the correct link:
If you're using kotlin, it will be

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:17.3.0
```

Comment: I added  Could not find com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.4.0. as documentations says - but i'm still getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: @OneBigQuestion if you're using the BoM, try removing the `:17.4.0` part

Comment: @BenLeggiero I was not, but i tried and i get the same message..

Comment: @OneBigQuestion Thanks for trying! Perhaps try asking a new question with details about your specific problem 